# Kivy RecycleView - How do you scroll with keyboard input?

Tags: scroll, keyboard, android-recyclerview, kivy

How do you scroll a RecycleView with the keyboard?

I would like the up/down keys to move the current selection up and down and keep that in the viewport.

For bonus points I would like the page up/page down keys to scroll a page at a time.

I have a working recycleview and keyboard input so far but can't work out how to connect them.

```
import subprocess

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.video import Video
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
#from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1680')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '1050')
#Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 'auto')
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.fullscreen = True

Builder.load_string('''
<MyVideo>:
    state: "play"
    options:  {'eos': 'loop'}
<SelectableLabel>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    list_id : app.root.ids["list_id"]
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected else (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    #size: 500,500
<RV>:
    viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        padding: 20
        default_size: None, dp(150)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        #size_hint_x: 1
        allow_stretch: True
        height: self.minimum_height
        #width: 500 #self.minimum_width
        orientation: 'vertical'
        multiselect: False
        touch_multiselect: False
<Mame>:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    RV:
        id: list_id
        video_id : video_id
        index: 0
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Image:
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: True
            size_hint_y: None
            size_hint_x: None
            width: self.parent.width
            height: self.parent.width/self.image_ratio
            source: "M:\MAME\marquees\%s.png"  % list_id.data[list_id.index]["game"]
        MyVideo:
            id: video_id
            allow_stretch: True
            #keep_ratio: False
            #size_hint_y: None
            #size_hint_x: None
            #width: self.parent.width
            #height: self.parent.width/self.image_ratio
            source : "V:\%s.mp4"  % list_id.data[list_id.index]["game"]
        Image:
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: True
            size_hint_y: None
            size_hint_x: None
            width: self.parent.width
            height: self.parent.width/self.image_ratio
            source : "M:\MAME\cpanel\%s.png"  % list_id.data[list_id.index]["game"]
    Image:
        source : "M:\MAME\cabinets\%s.png"  % list_id.data[list_id.index]["game"]
''')

class MyVideo(Video):
    def _do_video_load(self, *largs):
        try:
            return super(MyVideo, self)._do_video_load(largs)
        except:
            return

class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''



class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Image):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            if touch.is_double_tap:
                #self.selectable = False
                self.list_id.launch(self.index)
                return
            else:
                return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected
        if is_selected:
            self.list_id.index = index
            #print("selection changed to {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
        else:
            pass
            #print("selection removed for {0}".format(rv.data[index]))


class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(
            self._keyboard_closed, self, 'text')
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        f = open('golden.ini','r')
        lines = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        self.data = [{'source': "M:\MAME\marquees\%s.png"  % x.strip(), 'game': x.strip(), 'text': x.strip().capitalize()} for x in lines]

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        print('My keyboard have been closed!')
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        print('The key', keycode, 'have been pressed')
        print(' - text is %r' % text)
        print(' - modifiers are %r' % modifiers)

        # Keycode is composed of an integer + a string
        # If we hit escape, release the keyboard
        #if keycode[1] == 'escape':
        #    keyboard.release()
        if keycode[1] == 'up':
            if self.index > 0:
                self.index = self.index -1
        elif keycode[1] == 'down':
            if self.index < len(self.data)-1:
                self.index = self.index + 1


        # Return True to accept the key. Otherwise, it will be used by
        # the system.
        return True

    def launch(self,index):
        self.video_id.state = "stop"
        Window.minimize()
        #subprocess.Popen([r"C:\MAME\mame.exe", self.data[index].get("game")],cwd=r"C:\MAME")
        subprocess.call([r"C:\MAME\mame.exe", self.data[index].get("game")],cwd=r"C:\MAME")

        Window.fullscreen = True
        Window.restore()
        self.video_id.state = "play"

class Mame(BoxLayout):

    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Mame()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: There you go. My secret source. ;) It is based on the example code for RecycleView.